# Returning rows in SQL where there is no credit or debit GL Activity

Tags: sql, sql-server, accounting

I am trying to write a sql query that will show a row for all 12 of the Fiscal Periods instead of just the ones with values. The below Microsoft Query screen shot is showing what I am currently seeing based on the below SQL Query screen shot that is entered. I am currently only returning rows for FiscalPeriods 1,3,4,5,6,7,8. What I want to achieve is to return rows for 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12.

I would assume that it's only currently returning rows for 1,3,4,5,6,7,8 because there are values in either the debitamount or creditamount fields and no values for any of the other fields for these columns.

Can someone please write the sql query I would use so that I could return all rows for 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12 with values of "0" in the debitamount and creditamount columns where there are no values?

***Microsoft Query***
[image: Microsoft Query]

***SQL Query***
[image: SQL Query]

Comment: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/5221149)

Comment: You need `LEFT` join

Answer (score 0):

Do a `FULL JOIN` against a table with all the periods, e.g. an inline `VALUES` table, and use `COALESCE(...)` to fill the missing data with defaults.

See [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d14206/6) for full demo.

```
SELECT COALESCE(t.FiscalYear, v.FiscalYear) AS FiscalYear
     , COALESCE(t.FiscalPeriod, v.FiscalPeriod) AS FiscalPeriod
     , COALESCE(t.CreditAmount, 0) AS CreditAmount
  FROM MyTable t
  FULL JOIN ( VALUES ('2020', '01'), ('2020', '02'), ('2020', '03'), ('2020', '04')
                   , ('2020', '05'), ('2020', '06'), ('2020', '07'), ('2020', '08')
                   , ('2020', '09'), ('2020', '10'), ('2020', '11'), ('2020', '12')
            ) AS v (FiscalYear, FiscalPeriod)
              ON v.FiscalYear = t.FiscalYear
             AND v.FiscalPeriod = t.FiscalPeriod
 ORDER BY 1, 2
```

*Output*

```
FiscalYear  FiscalPeriod  CreditAmount
2020        01            94
2020        02            0
2020        03            142.9
2020        04            1681.5
2020        05            5826.26
2020        06            5978.99
2020        07            4401.37
2020        08            6784.09
2020        09            0
2020        10            0
2020        11            0
2020        12            0
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply need a `LEFT JOIN`.  The first "table" is a list of the periods that you want; the second is your existing query:

```
WITH q AS (
      <your query here>
     )
SELECT q.FiscalYear, q.FiscalPeriod,       
       COALESCE(q.CreditAmount, 0) AS CreditAmount,
       . . .
FROM (VALUES ('2020', '01'), ('2020', '02'), ('2020', '03'), ('2020', '04'),
              ('2020', '05'), ('2020', '06'), ('2020', '07'), ('2020', '08'),
              ('2020', '09'), ('2020', '10'), ('2020', '11'), ('2020', '12')
     ) v(FiscalYear, FiscalPeriod)
     ON v.FiscalYear = q.FiscalYear AND
        v.FiscalPeriod = q.FiscalPeriod
 ORDER BY 1, 2
```